# unable to view table when the table view controller loads

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building an app using swift in Xcode 8.0.  I am unable to see the contents of my table view control.  The class that is tied to it seems already has the tableview datasource and delegate protocols built  in.  The error I get is libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

here is the code that the table view is tied to:

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return meals.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //TableView cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier
        let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell


        // Fetchess the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
        cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
        cell.ratingControl2.rating = meal.rating


        // Configure the cell...


        return cell
    }
```

below is the code that the table cell tied to

```
 import UIKit

class MealTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl2: RatingControl2!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**problem solved!!!**

I forgot to add the cell identifier file to the Table cell view.  thx

Comment: Can you show us some of your code on how you are showing content into your table view?

Comment: You most probably are having indexing issues in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method of the UITableViewDataSource protocol.... Go through that once.... Ur number of cells might have gone higher than the number items your array consist to be displayed on the table